# Multiple plots with variable color in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot multiple plots on the same graph in R, and have them color-coded according to a third variable, but I don't know how to do this within one data frame in ggplot2.

So for example my data could look like (made up data):

```
Time = [1 2 3 4 5]

YData = [10 11  9 10 12]
        [ 5  3  4  6  9]

ColorData = [2.5 2.6 2.7 2.8 2.9]
            [0.1 1.2 2.4 1.6 0.2]
```

I need to plot "YData[1,] vs Time" with points colored on some color-scale according to ColorData[1,]. Then I need to plot "YData[2,] vs Time" with points on a color-scale according to ColorData[2,]. Both plots would go on the same axes. In practice my matrices will be enormous so I can't plot each thing manually. Any ideas how I could do this?

#### data example :

```
dx <- data.frame(Time = c(1, 2, 3 ,4, 5), 
                 YData1 = c(10 ,11  ,9 ,10 ,12),
                 YData2 = c(5  ,3  ,4  ,6  ,9),
                 ColorData1 = c(2.5 ,2.6 ,2.7, 2.8, 2.9),
                 ColorData2 =  c(0.1, 1.2, 2.4, 1.6, 0.2)
                 )
```

Code without color:

```
 library(reshape2)
 dx.melted = melt(dx, id = "Time")
 ggplot(data = dx.melted, aes(x = Time, y = value)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: Hi, your problem is quite is easy. Could you provide at least a reproducible example ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. My time list is 1000 in length and I have a 32x1000 matrix for YData and ColorData, but I don't know if posting that would help at all. I'm sorry, I know it's probably a simple problem for those familiar with R, but I have looked and not been able to find a way to do it. The closest thing I've seen is using the melt() function to plot multiple graphs, but that does not help me if I also have color data. (Also I'm not sure why I'm getting downvoted...)

Comment: You could present your data in valid R syntax. Even better would be creating the objects in R and using `dput()`. Essentially, now, you're asking people to copy/paste your code, add commas, replace `[]` with `c()` or calls to `matrix()`.

Comment: @user2520385 you get downvoted ( I think ) , beacause you don't provide a reproducible example and you don't show what you have so far tried.

Comment: Looks like @agstudy has you covered, but this is the kind of thing it's nice to do yourself.

Comment: Thanks agstudy and point taken Gregor. I was just trying to present the data in pseudocode as a syntax-independent illustrative aid. I wasn't meaning for people to copy anything. Also I don't have a reproducible example because I don't know how to write the code, basically. I guess I can post what I know about plotting multiple plots on a single graph, but once color is added I have no idea

Comment: R questions on SO are a bit different than other language questions (I think) largely due to R being interpretable. There's a strong expectation that your code will be valid and will run---even if it's just data definitions. Even if you don't have a plot, using valid syntax makes your data easily reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reshape your data before plotting. Usually we use the `reshape` command to put data in the long format. Here I am using a manual method but that it is general to transform your 32 columns data.frame.

```
dx_reshaped <- data.frame(Time=dx[,1],
                          stack(dx[,(grep('YData',colnames(dx)))]),
                          stack(dx[,(grep('Color',colnames(dx)))]))
```

Then you plot it like using `ggplot2`. I am using 2 geoms to distinguish the (the *ydata type* and the *color type*).

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=dx_reshaped,aes(Time,values)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=ind),size=4) +
  geom_line(aes(color=values.1,group=ind))
```

[image]